# Getting the texture map from a 3D model

Tags: javascript, 3d, texture-mapping

I have built a 3d display application in Javascript/canvas it works quite well. I recently implemented the ability to map textures.

I import 3d models from stl format which work well since they only store tris so are easy to import since I haven't got to break them up but they don't store textures.

The way textures are stored is as such

```
textureObject(){
  this.img=image //Js image object
  this.triArray=[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...]//Map of where polys

  function returnImage(int i){
    //returns a cropped triangle around the coordinates in the triArray. 
  }
}
```

The actual implementation is a bit different but thats the meat and gravy of it. Although it's not perfect texture mapping it's just an affine transformation which can look ugly as sin but is good enough for me.

My issue is that I am not sure how to save the triArray from a 3d object which is already created so that I don't have to create a brand new file format just for this project.

I think I have 2 options:

Making an importer for another file format if there is one which stores it's texture coordinate information in the file. (But which file format?)

OR

OR is there one standard way of mapping textures to objects which I could then implement to create my array? (What is the method?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this file format is something you're looking for? I think a lot of 3d modeling programs actually export to this format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj

Comment: I eventually solved this myself, I did use STL and I found out how they are laid out and wrote a viewer (http://sobriety.1free.ws/index.php?action=OBJViewer) I will implement it in my main code when I can get my hands on some sub 100tri models or I learn how to make my own.